# Make function variable available to other php files

Tags: php

I have a paging.php file, which has a function `latest($imagesPerPage, $site) {`.

Inside that function, I have a variable $lastPage:

```
$catResult->data_seek(0); 
$totalComics = 0;
while ($row = $catResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $totalComics++;
}

global $lastPage;
$lastPage = ceil($totalComics/$imagesPerPage);
```

I have another file, homepage.php, which needs to use `$lastPage` defined above in the paging.php file's "latest()" function.

---

At the top of homepage.php, I include the paging file: `include 'scripts/paging.php';`

I then call `<?php echo latest(15, $site); ?>` to display some images...

And below, I want to handle page numbers and navigation, and need to use the $lastPage variable:

```
    for($i = 1; $i <= $lastPage; $i++) {
        echo '<li><span class=navItems><a href="?site=' . $site . '&cat=' . $cat . '&page=' . $i .'">' . $i . '</a></span></li>';
    }
```

homepage.php keeps complaining that $lastPage is undefined... I've tried `global $lastPage`, `$GLOBALS[$lastPage]`... but it's still not available.

---

My questions are:

1. How can I make `$lastPage` available outside the function to the homepage.php file?
2. How can I make `$lastPage` available to other functions within paging.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is include the file that contains the function.

If that file contains other code which you don't want to be included in the other file, then make a functions file; a file dedicated to housing functions which you can include in other pages.

Take a look at [PHP's include function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

**Example, if your function was in a file called `functions.inc.php`:**

```
include("functions.inc.php");

// Here you can use the function
```

**Concerning `$lastPage` variable not being accessible try this:**

```
// Inside imageDisplay.php -- OUTSIDE OF THE FUNCTION ---
$lastPage = "Whatever it's value needs to be"; // If we declare it outside the function we can use it on any page which includes this file

function paging() {
    global $lastPage; // This now means you can use the $lastPage variable inside the function
    ...
}
```

Hopefully this helps to explain how you can use the `$lastPage` variable outside of the function and on included pages as well as inside the function.

Comment: I already included imageDisplay.php (which houses the functions I wish to use) at the top of homepage.php

Comment: @Growler This is the basis of the logic, what else do you need; are you saying it simply is not working?

Comment: I've included the file imageDisplay.php, which has function paging(); In paging() I declare variable $lastPage~ is it not available to the other file homepage.php because I've defined $lastPage INSIDE paging() function? If so, do I have to make it global?

Comment: @Growler Yes Growler that's correct, I'll edit my answer showing how to do it.